# Can Windows 8 Damage a Hard Disk?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, laptop, hardware-failure

I have a Toshiba Satellite C660 Laptop which is having **Intel Core i3 processor**, **2GB RAM**, **512MB Graphics** along with **320GB Hard disk**. Few weeks ago it suddenly stopped working and after researching I found that the hard disk was damaged and there we physical bad sectors. I was using Windows 8 Pro on this laptop. It's was a bit slow. I want to know Can Windows 8 damage a hard disk? This sounds a bit silly but really this is what I know! I asked Toshiba customer care and they told me that Windows 8 is compatible, but they don't recommend it to be used on this laptop. Please tell me Can a hard disk damaged by an Operating System like Windows 8? I also want to tell you that sometimes the disk usage reached to 100%. Please tell me!

Comment: Hard drives are one of the top failure points in any computer, Windows 8 does not damage a hard drive any more than any other OS though

Comment: So you want to say that my hard disk is not damaged by Windows 8, and there was some other reason? My laptop was working fine with the previous OS Windows 7.

Comment: Not damaged by Windows 8: correct; Some other reason, hard drives fail, and they fail often. If you owned a computer repair business and 100 laptops came in, 90 of them would probably be hard drive failures.

Comment: Sounds like the hardware just failed. Software cannot cause hardware to fail. Windows 8 is on millions of machines, if there was a problem, there would be a much higher failure rate then just your machine. Its not recommend because they have not provided drivers to support it. Your laptop was working previously because it didn't have bad sectors. Based on the size your looking at a HDD that was at least 4 years old.  Most hdd warranties are only 3, used to be 5, but the failure rate after a certain point forced that to be reduced.

Comment: Poor and uneven work with some elements of the file system leads to failure of the hdd. For example, because of problems with the registry files and caching frequently accessed. Often falling windows-systems for problems with the disc begins with a message that the registry file not found). In your case, though we are talking about the lack of power of the laptop. Not on the behavior of the operating system.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes you're right but after looking at Toshiba's official website I've found that my laptop is supported by Windows 8 [link](http://goo.gl/5j5bG6). And also the drivers are available at their website (http://goo.gl/cvDGa4). But that's also true that if this is problem with Windows 8 there will be much higher failure rate. I'm bit confused. I've now installed a new hard disk, please tell me should I install Windows 8 on that?

Comment: @Daman - Windows 8 did not cause the hardware failure, the HDD failing because its a mechanical device, and all mechanical devices will fail at some point in the lifespan is the reason it failed.  You will have to decide on your own, if you want to use Windows 8, a level 1 Toshiba support just gave their opinion of Windows 8.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for explaining me. But some people say that insufficient power can cause such an issue. Is that true? Are there some differences between power consumption of Windows 8 and older operating systems like Windows 7?

Comment: There would be no significant difference in the power delivered to the drive between Windows 8 and prior versions -- the OS does not control the drive power, other than to turn them on and off.  Different pieces of software *will* tend to produce different access patterns in the drive, and this can expose drive weaknesses.  In particular, newer OS versions are more optimized for SSDs and may have different reference patterns from older OS versions.  And the simple act of installing a new OS probably produces the equivalent 6-12 months of "normal" wear on the primary disk drive.

Comment: The one thing that *could* kill the drive is a bad driver routine -- either the wrong one installed or a driver that was buggy from the software foundry.

Comment: @Ramhound - Software definitely *can* cause hardware failures.  But that's unlikely in this case.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Why this is unlikely in this case? When I first installed Windows 8 on my laptop the only issue I was facing was the Adaptive brightness. So I just installed a display driver my AMD. Can that driver cause such an issue?

Comment: @DanielRHicks - I started to list the possability of a driver causing a problem, which has been a problem in the past with Nvidia cards, but those problems in the end were actually caused by bad soldering so I decided not bother to fully explain my comment.  The number of times software actually caused working hardware to fail, on a large enough scale to be the reason the hardware failed, wasn't worth trying to explain.  I am fully aware software could cause a hardware failure to surface.

Comment: @Daman - Your HDD just failed.  The use of the HDD in general caused the bad sectors to be discovered, critical system files were located on them, which lead to your problem.  The installation of your drivers DID NOT cause the problem.

Comment: Well.. installing a whole new OS is kind of a "stressfull" operation for a HDD, so... as everyone said.... your drive just failed

Comment: @Ramhound - You are correct that software-caused hardware failures are exceptionally rare.  But you said *Software cannot cause hardware to fail*, and that is not true.  I had a phone screen literally melt due to a "hard" software loop, and in the early days of disk drives it was all to common for the access arm to be damaged by improper seeks.  Not to mention all the ways you can overheat a processor or video adapter and damage it.